# How to delete a group of test cases in VSTS permanently

Tags: azure-devops

I imported 1000 test cases into my project and I would like a quick way to delete them.  Currently I can only delete them one at a time by opening each individual test case and selecting "Permanently delete" from the menu.  Is there a way to delete a group of test cases at a time (batch delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Work item batch operations REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/batch), for example:

POST: `https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0`

JSON (Work items: 741,742):

```
[
     {
    "method": "DELETE",
    "uri": "/_apis/wit/workitems/741?api-version=1.0"
    },
     {
    "method": "DELETE",
    "uri": "/_apis/wit/workitems/742?api-version=1.0"
    }
]
```